# setContentView() and findViewById() don't work in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, view, fragment

I wrote a working app in Kotlin in an empty activity and it worked. Then I created a tab activity project, then in com.example.tabbed added a new Fragment(blank), then inside the onCreate() i pasted my code from the last app. I copied the xml file to and named it fragment_1. After that it gives me errors on setContentView() and findViewById().
That's the Fragment1.kt file:

```
package com.example.tabbed

import android.R
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.core.view.isVisible
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment


private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

class Fragment1 : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var ulamekLabel: TextView
    private lateinit var licznik: EditText
    private lateinit var mianownik: EditText
    private lateinit var kUlamkowa: TextView
    private lateinit var calosci: TextView
    private lateinit var nLicznik: TextView
    private lateinit var nMianownik: TextView
    private lateinit var kreska: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_1)
        ulamekLabel = findViewById(R.id.ulamekLabel)
        licznik = findViewById(R.id.licznik)
        mianownik = findViewById(R.id.mianownik)
        kUlamkowa = findViewById(R.id.kUlamkowa)
        calosci = findViewById(R.id.calosci)
        nLicznik = findViewById(R.id.nLicznik)
        nMianownik = findViewById(R.id.nMianownik)
        kreska = findViewById(R.id.kreska)

        kreska.isVisible = false

        licznik.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3:     Int) {}

            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                skracamy()
            }

        })
        mianownik.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}

            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}

            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
                skracamy()
            }

        })
    }

    private fun skracamy() {
        if (licznik.text.isEmpty() || mianownik.text.isEmpty()) {
            calosci.text = "0"
            calosci.isVisible = false
            nLicznik.text = "0"
            nLicznik.isVisible = false
            nMianownik.text = "0"
            nMianownik.isVisible = false
            kreska.isVisible = false
            return
        }
        val a = licznik.text.toString().toInt()
        val b = mianownik.text.toString().toInt()

        val l = (a / nwd(a,b)).toString().toInt()
        val m = (b / nwd(a,b)).toString().toInt()

        val c = (l/m).toString().toInt()
        val d = (l%m).toString().toInt()

        calosci.isVisible = true
        nLicznik.isVisible = true
        nMianownik.isVisible = true
        kreska.isVisible = true

        if(c != 0 && d != 0) {
            calosci.text = c.toString()
            nLicznik.text = d.toString()
            nMianownik.text = m.toString()
        }
        else if(d != 0 && c == 0) {
            calosci.text = ""
            nLicznik.text = d.toString()
            nMianownik.text = m.toString()
        }
        else {
            calosci.text = c.toString()
            nLicznik.text = ""
            nMianownik.text = ""
        }
    }

    private fun nwd(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
        return if (b != 0) nwd(b, a % b) else a
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false)
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            Fragment1().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Maybe I pasted the code in the wrong place or something? I'm a beginner in programing for android. Please help.

Comment: Look like copy pasted java code over kotlin migration. I recommend using View Binding. Is simply and error less

Comment: While following this: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding i still get a not working setContentView()

Comment: Can u send logcat logs?

Comment: e: /Users/grzesiek/Desktop/tabbed/app/src/main/java/com/example/tabbed/Fragment1.kt: (36, 9): Unresolved reference: setContentView

Comment: I don't remain u use fragments. Fragment != Activity. For it, u need to use onCreateView and onViewCrated. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-fragments-android/

Comment: You have copied activity code into a fragment - that won't work. In a fragment if you don't use binding you would use something like `rootView.findViewById` to get views.

Comment: Fragments are very different than activities. You should read the documentation on them and their lifecycles before trying to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your return value in the override methods.

In my case in onCreateView() [Using data binding]:

I was returning this

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.f_login, container, false)
```

instead of this

```
return binding.root
```